# Android Cannot find identifier for xhdpi

Tags: android, android-layout

Ok in my manifest i have

```
  <supports-screens 
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              />
```

When i go to compile i get a error that says

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'
```

I have my drawable folders laid out as such:

```
/res
    /drawable
    /drawable-ldpi
    /drawable-mdpi
    /drawable-hdpi
    /drawable-xhdpi
```

What am i missing?

Comment: What is the API level you are using ..

Comment: im using 8 with the target set to 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably means that the "project target" is set to be lower than 9 (that's when xlargeScreens attribute is added). To change it:

1. Find a file in your Eclipse project root called
   "project.properties", open it and set the "target" value to 9 or
   higher, save and close.
2. On Eclipse tool bar, select Project ->Clean... to clean the project
   and recompile, at which point the project should compile without any
   issues.

Comment: on the link provided above it states xhdpi: Extra high-density screens; approximately 320dpi. Added in API Level 8

Comment: @mpeerman xhdpi is added in API Level 8, but android:xlargeScreens is added in API Level 9 (see [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#xlarge)), since your issue is with android:xlargeScreens, the answer is targeted to allowing android:xlargeScreens tag to be compiled as well.

Answer (score 0):

To use `xlargeScreens`, you need to use SDK with level **9** and your tools should match as well.

This is documented here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: on the link provided above it states xhdpi: Extra high-density screens; approximately 320dpi. Added in API Level 8